# Black screen while watching youtube videos

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card, black-screen-of-death

nearly every time, while I'm watching a video on YouTube, my monitor losts signal from my graphic card. Sometimes the driver is resetting, but often I got a black screen and thats it.

My System
Windows 7 x64
Intel Quad-Core Q6600
NVIDIA GTS250 with currently 310.54 BETA (happens also with 306.97)

Windows is ud to date. I think that the new WDDM1.2 Driver from Microsoft is the problem, after the installation of the update, this problems appeared.

Can anyone tell me how to downgrade WDDM1.2 to WDDM1.1 or another solution?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english.
zeyorama

Comment: have you tried downloading and installing the old driver?

Comment: Tried 296.10, doesn't work.

Comment: Win7 doesn't support WDDM 1.2, only WDDM 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Control Panel > Devices and Printers
```

your graphics card should be listed here, right click on it and select "Properties"

click on the "Hardware" tab at the top, then select your graphics card and again click on the "Properties" button

from here select the "Driver" tab and then there should be "Driver Details", "Update Driver...", and "Roll Back Driver" buttons.

Answer (score -1):

Hey there good people,

I've had my screen go black and immediately recover for a while now, which was impossible to deal with. It would start after about 10-30 min after power up and not stop anymore when sim racing, watching videos (especially on full screen) or be at it's worst while just on plain desktop. 
I checked everything (cables, drivers, power options etc.) and read every forum I could find about this common problem. After having tried most of all the different suggestions, still no luck... But one thing was nowhere mentioned, and I came upon this randomly while going through the setting on my monitor (which I did already several times before), but this time I changed the power settings from "PC" back to "AV" (Samsung 2770), and voila!

Solved! At least till now, a week in - knock on wood...

No idea how these setting got changed, probably by myself without knowing what I was doing, but I hope this simple solution will help many of you frustrated fellas and ladies out there to have one less annoyance in your lives.

God bless!